# What is the right tag for a computer SMPS? power supply seems to be too generic

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

A desktop computer SMPS / power supply unit is widely known as SMPS and it referrers to the desktop computer Power Unit. On the other had a "power supply" or "power-supply" tag seems to be too broad and generic as the power supply term can be applied to anything that supplies the power.

Can we consider the tag SMPS right in this context?

Comment: It's the first time I've ever seen the term “SMPS”, and while I'm not a hardware expert, I *have* built a few PCs from parts.

Comment: @Gilles I guess its all about the geographic location we live and the colloquial terms that you use, in India no one knows what is a PSU , we use SMPS all over here, But I see that UK and US its PSU that makes more sense

Comment: @ClainDsilva: Sounds like the perfect case for a tag synonym, and mentioning alternate names in the tag wiki

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags are *meant* to be generic, so that questions in related subjects get grouped together. The place to specify further is in the question body.

With regard to SMPS, I'd say that the [power-supply](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-supply) tag is fine for it - after all, it's a unit that supplies power.

Comment: while its true that SMPS is the unit that supplies power, I beg to differ as Battery, Laptop Charger etc also supplies power yet they are different in behavior and physical structure. Also trouble shooting method for each of these are different.

Comment: @ClainDsilva But in a computer, the “power supply” or “power supply unit” (commonly abbreviated “PSU”) is the unit that converts mains power. A laptop charger is a power supply. A battery is not a power supply.